# Contributing to the same GitHub project using both IntelliJ Idea and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, intellij-idea

My question is simple. I'm developing an app on GitHub using Android Studio. Should I accept contributions from someone using ItelliJ Idea?

Comment: Android Studio is built from the same source as the Android plugin for IntelliJ Idea, so I don't see how you would even find what IDE is being used by the contributors

Comment: IDE here does not matter as long as you both are using the same build-tool to build what you are building

Comment: Martheen a lot of new .idea xml files and an iml file were added in a commit just changing a md file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let every user use their preferred editor to edit the files in your project.  It should not matter what editor a user uses to work on your project.

*However*, you should not check in any files specific to *any* editor, whether that's Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA, or something else.  All tooling should be agnostic to the editor and invoked using a standard build or linting tool in your environment.  Those are the best practices for all projects.

If you need things like standard ways to express indentations, character sets, and line endings, that's what [EditorConfig files](https://editorconfig.org/) are for.  They are supported by some editors natively, while others require a plugin.